# Barcode Scanning using C# with Special Characters Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I have a program which can scan barcode , it actually works but I encounter problem if the length of data is 18 characters long with "-".

When I try to scan it cuts the data to 14 characters only. How can I make this 18 character string scan properly and display on textbox

Refer to Code Below

App Config:

```
<add key="Baudrate" value="9600"/>
<add key="Parity" value="0"/>
<add key="DataBits" value="8"/>
<add key="StopBits" value="1"/>
```

Source Code on Event :

```
 private void ScannerEvent(object sender, AlertEventArgs alertEvent)
        {
           

            log.Info(Common.Common.LineNumber() + "ScannerEvent");

            log.Info("alertEvent: " + alertEvent.Data);


            log.Info("Length of Data: " + alertEvent.Data.Length);
            
            try
            {
                
                txtLabel.Text = alertEvent.Data;
                
  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
```

Screenshot below on result of scanning:
[scanerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teGEP.png)

Comment: What symbology are you using? Some barcodes can only store a limited number of characters.

Comment: @DourHighArch "-" / hyphen

Comment: You need to [learn what a symbology is](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/resource-library/faq/barcode-scanning/what-is-barcode-symbology.html).

Comment: its code 128 @DourHighArch

Comment: I tried removing hyphen , and encoded letters and numbers 18 characters but its still  not scanning properly. It still displays 14 characters on textbox

Comment: Maybe it's customizing the scanner hardware settings? Why not try using the settings barcode to restore the factory default settings? Then, as is often the case with other questions, please present the appropriate barcode image taken at high resolution/contrast/brightness. That may make it easier to get advice and answers.

Comment: By the way, most barcode scanners can be configured to appear as keyboards. This is usually the easiest method to interact with them